# Euler equation for the functional has the form: $f_y-f_xy'-\frac{fy''}{1+y'^2}=0$

Tags: analysis, calculus-of-variations

I want to show that the Euler equation for the functional $J(y)= \int_a^b f(x,y) \sqrt{1+y'^2}dx$ has the form:

$$f_y-f_xy'-\frac{fy''}{1+y'^2}=0$$

$$L(x,y,y')= f(x,y) \sqrt{1+y'^2} dx$$

Substituting $L_y(x,y,y')=f_y(x,y) \sqrt{1+y'^2}, \ L_{y'}(x,y,y')= f(x,y) \frac{y'}{\sqrt{1+y'^2}}$, I got the following:

$$f_y(1+y'^2)-f_x y'- f y''+ \frac{f (y')^2}{(1+y'^2)}=0$$

Can we get from this relation to the desired one, or have I done something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The Euler–Lagrange equation is
$$ L_y - \frac{dL_{y'} }{dx} = 0. $$
You have $L_y=f_y \sqrt{1+y'^2}$ fine. And
$$ L_{y'} = f \frac{y'}{\sqrt{1+y'^2}}. $$
Now we have to take the total derivative of this:
$$ \frac{dL_{y'}}{dx} = \frac{y'}{\sqrt{1+y'^2}}\frac{d}{dx} f(x,y) + f \frac{d}{dx} \frac{y'}{\sqrt{1+y'^2}} \\
= \frac{y'}{\sqrt{1+y'^2}} (f_x+y' f_y) + f \frac{y''\sqrt{1+y'^2}+ \frac{y'y''}{\sqrt{1+y'^2}}}{1+y'^2} \\
=\frac{y'}{\sqrt{1+y'^2}} (f_x+y' f_y) + f \frac{y''}{(1+y'^2)^{3/2}}. $$
Therefore the E–L equation is
$$ 0 = f_y \sqrt{1+y'^2} - \frac{y'}{\sqrt{1+y'^2}} (f_x+y' f_y) - f \frac{y''}{(1+y'^2)^{3/2}};  $$
multiplying through by $\sqrt{1+y'^2}$ gives
$$ 0 = f_y (1+y'^2) - y' f_x - y'^2 f_y - \frac{y''f}{1+y'^2}, $$
which cancels to give the result. Basically, you didn't take the total derivative correctly.